# Python RegEx not working with uppercase?

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract the hostname from a ping command with Python RegEx. I can't figure out why my regex below finds the first line with lowercase but not the one with uppercase. Appreciate if someone can suggest an alternate solution. Thanks

```
Pinging\s?(\w*)[^A-Z]*(?=.domain.com)
```

Pinging abc1-de-fgh.domain.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data: - Found this one

Pinging ABC1-DE-FGH.domain.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data: - Do not find this one

Comment: your second input line doesn't have `.domain.com`. So it should not be matched

Comment: Use something simpler like `/Pinging ([\w.-]+) /`. Then get the hostname from that capture.

Comment: Is the hostname `abc1-de-fgh` and `ABC1-DE-FGH`? `\w*` matches the `abc1` in the first example, so you just need to use `Pinging\s+([^.]+)` (`[^.]+` will match 1 or more chars other than `.`).

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You get a match with the first input like this:

- `Pinging` is matched with `Pinging`
- is matched with `\s?`
- `abc1` is matched and captured with `(\w*)`
- `-de-fgh` is matched with `[^A-Z]*`
- `(?=.domain.com)` asserts there is any char + `domain` + any char + `com` right after `fgh`.

The second regex does not match because of the uppercase chars that **cannot** be matched with `[^A-Z]*`. The `Pinging ABC1` part is  matched the same way as above, but `-` cannot be matched with `(\w*)` and the `[^A-Z]*` matches any 0+ chars other than uppercase chars.

Use

```
Pinging\s?([^.]*)(?=\.domain\.com)
```

where `[^.]*` matches any 0+ chars other than `.` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2WWDOD/1)) or a simpler

```
Pinging\s?(.*?)(?=\.domain\.com)
```

with `.*?` lazy dot matching pattern matching any 0+ chars, as few as possible.
 [See another demo](https://regex101.com/r/2WWDOD/2).